# GPG key created with sudo cannot be used to sign Git commit

Tags: git, gnupg

When I attempt to create a new key for Github with this command:

```
gpg --full-gen-key
```

I keep receiving this error:

```
gpg: no writable public keyring found: Not found
Key generation failed: Not found
```

So I added `sudo` in front of the command and the key was created. Then I added the key to Github and set the signing key to Git. However, when I tested the key with a new commit, it gave me this error:

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I assumed it's because I used `sudo` but I cannot create a key otherwise. It keeps giving the public keyring error every I use `gpg` alone. Any clarification on this is appreciated.

Comment: Check permissions of files/directories, you shouldn't use `sudo` to get around the problem of creating keys - but find & fix what I'm betting is a file permissions issue created by a prior use of `sudo` where you shouldn't have used it.

Comment: I found out permission of `pubring.kbx` is root. In this case should I change its permission or create a `pubring.gpg` instead?